# SQL - pull clients (1 client per row in result set) and most recent order date for those clients

Tags: sql, join

Below is some SQL to pull a list of clients.  As you can see I added the lines annotated by "-- ADDED"--a new field, a join and an order by.  I'm trying to display one client per row in my result set, but for each client, I want to display the most recent order.  What's the best way to do this?  Should I put a where in my JOIN or use the TOP 1?  I suppose there are a few ways, but I want to make it as efficient as possible.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),client.identifyingnumber) As [Client ID], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,client.name) As [Client Name], 
    client.clientid As [Id],
    CONVERT(CHAR(10),[ecom_order].[order_date],101)  -- ADDED
FROM  
    client 
    JOIN clientstatus ON client.clientstatusid = clientstatus.clientstatusid 
    JOIN clienttype ON clienttype.clienttypeid = client.clienttypeid 
    -- keep left outer join since some clients won't have any orders, thus no last order
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ecom_order] ON client.clientid = [ecom_order].clientid -- ADDED
WHERE  
    client.name LIKE '%_%' 
    AND 
    client.name <= (
        SELECT MAX(maxsubquery.ordercolumn) FROM (
            SELECT 
                TOP 10 client.name AS ordercolumn 
            FROM  
                client 
                JOIN clientstatus ON client.clientstatusid = clientstatus.clientstatusid 
                JOIN clienttype ON clienttype.clienttypeid = client.clienttypeid 
            WHERE  
                client.name LIKE '%_%' 
            ORDER BY client.name
        ) 
        AS maxsubquery)
 ORDER BY 
    client.name,
    [ecom_order].order_date DESC -- ADDED
```

**Test Data Result Set Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   SELECT 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),client.identifyingnumber) As [Client ID], 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,client.name) As [Client Name], 
        client.clientid As [Id],
      -- Change to get latest
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),Max([ecom_order].[order_date]),101)       
     FROM  client 
        JOIN clientstatus ON client.clientstatusid = clientstatus.clientstatusid 
        JOIN clienttype ON clienttype.clienttypeid = client.clienttypeid 
        -- keep left outer join since some clients won't have any orders, 
     -- thus no last order
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [ecom_order] ON client.clientid = [ecom_order].clientid 
    WHERE  
        client.name LIKE '%_%' 
        AND 
        client.name <= (
            SELECT MAX(maxsubquery.ordercolumn) FROM (
                SELECT 
                    TOP 10 client.name AS ordercolumn 
                FROM  
                    client 
                    JOIN clientstatus ON client.clientstatusid = clientstatus.clientstatusid 
                    JOIN clienttype ON clienttype.clienttypeid = client.clienttypeid 
                WHERE  
                    client.name LIKE '%_%' 
                ORDER BY client.name
            ) 
            AS maxsubquery)
     GROUP BY client.identifyingnumber,client.name,client.client_id
     ORDER BY 
        client.name
```

Comment: Just to remind myself later.. you modified the field formula, removed my extra order by line, and added the group by.  Seems to work!  Thanks for the quick response!  I'll accept it when it allows me to.